By bus (on the bus), by car (in the car), by motorbike (on the motorbike)
I'm reading an extensive book about articles written by Seonaid Beckwith.
In the book, I see the following:

We use 'no article' when we use a form of
transport with by:

By car*: We travelled by Ø car.
By bus: He goes to work by Ø bus.
By underground / metro / subway: I went home by Ø underground.
By plane: I hate travelling by Ø plane.
By train: We went to Scotland by Ø train.
By taxi*: I love going by Ø taxi.
By bike*: He gets around London by Ø bike.
By motorbike*: The parcels were delivered by Ø motorbike.
By boat / by ferry: We went by Ø boat to France.

*We don't use the car, the bike, the taxi or the motorbike in
the same way as the others. They are normal nouns.

What does the author mean by the last statement? Don't we use the other nouns in the list as normal (common) nouns too? For example: "I got on the train", "I got off the bus" etc.

There's always the dichotomy between the definite article referring to an individual vehicle vs a method. "I got on the train" is clearly an specific set of cars at a specific time. But "I don't like flying so I took the train." But we can't reverse this; we don't "take the plane." Any use of "the plane" refers to a specific aircraft (yeah yeah, or generalized archetype, "the plane was invented" etc.).

@AndyBonner (Said  as a remark only) generic use for such nouns as "plane" is much more often implemented by a plural. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=planes+were+invented%2C+the+plane+was+invented&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

@LPH Or as a more specific full word; the Wright Bros are more likely to have "invented the aeroplane" than "the plane."

@AndyBonner well, in the book, "the train" and "the plane" are in the same category, whereas "the car, the bike, the taxi and the motorbike" are put into a different one, and that's what my question is about.

Maybe it says elsewhere in the book?

I can't work out what he means.

There seems to be a lot of unexpected non-idiomacy hereabouts. As Andy partly observes, 'take the' works with bus / tube / train / boat / ferry but not others (in this sense; 'take the bike' means fasten it to the car roof, say). Take a works also with taxi and perhaps plane. 'I spend a lot of time on' works with my bike / the bus / the underground / the train / planes / the ferry.

Please excuse my ignorance and what does ' Ø ' mean?

The author of the book responded to my email and cleared it up. I quote:


I meant that we use 'the' with some forms of transport, like train or plane, when we're talking about the transport system in general. We can't do this with the words car, bike, taxi or motorbike.
So it's possible to say 'I'll take the train to London' without meaning a particular train. Here, I'm just talking about using the train system. But if I say 'I'll take the car', I mean a particular car, probably my car. With 'car' in this sentence, 'the' has its usual 'I'm talking about something the listener knows about' meaning.
Here's a quote from the previous section of the same book where I talk about this:

We often use 'the' when we are talking about a form of transport as a > general idea. We usually do this with public transport (not with cars or bikes) and we usually use verbs such as take, be on, get on and get off:
the bus
We took the bus to school.
the underground / metro / subway

She gets off the underground in central London.

the plane

It’s best to take the plane to New York City.

the train

Julie’s on the train at the moment.

the boat / ferry

You can take the ferry to France.

In all of these examples, I’m not talking about a particular bus, train or plane but rather the system of transport as an idea.


*We don't use the car, the bike, the taxi or the motorbike in the same way as the others. They are normal nouns.

The author is pointing out that when modes of transport are used in the agentive sense (by + noun), they are uncountable and do not require an article or determiner.
On the bus, in the car, on the motorbike are not agentive - they are locative: they tell you where you were when you travelled.
Essentially "on the motorbike" is the same in I sat on the motorbike, and I went on the motorbike,

But the footnote is saying something about the specific words that have the asterisk. There's something different between "car" (asterisk) and "bus" (no asterisk). It's not about "by" vs. "on".

Yes, but ALL of those words, inlcuding the ones the author set apart from the rest, can be used both in agentive and locative senses,"by car", "in the/a car"(first group) VS "by train" and "in/on the/a train" (second group), so what's the difference then?
